# how to build and create exe installer for eclispse rcp product

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

can anybody tell me how to create exe installer file for eclipse rcp product

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have exported you product using the [Product Export Wizard](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_Eclipse_product%3F), you will have a folder that includes an exe for launching your RCP application.

If you then want to create a packaged version for installing from a single exe, I've used the [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) in the past. Comes with some good examples, lets you easily create start menu entries and an uninstaller.

If you install [EclipseNSIS](http://eclipsensis.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) you can use its wizard to create the installer. New->Other->EclipseNSIS->NSIS Script. Takes you through it step by step and creates the script for you. You can also then run your installer build script right from eclipse.

Comment: thank you very much.. i will try and let you know thanks once again

Comment: how can i build exe of exported eclipse rcp application.

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: yes thank you. But now i m troubling how could i include exported folder to nsis. Can you please help me how can i create exe using nsis. I have created some scripts for exe, uninstaller. But i don't understand where to include exported eclipse.exe in nsis script

Comment: In your Section -Main include a line `File /r C:\Path\to\exported\eclipse\*` This specifies that all the files and subdirectories at `C:\Path\to\exported\eclipse\` are to be included in your installer.

Comment: when i included its creating zip file of folder instead of .exe

Comment: when i included its creating zip file of folder instead of .exe       Can you please mention steps so that i can create

Comment: Thanks Malcolm EclipseNSIS is very helpful. Just last question can you please tell me how to create shortcut of applicaton

Comment: Thanks Malcolm finally exe created with EclipseNSIS. Thank you very much for your all response.